# Class 'Timestamp' has no instance method 'isAfter' Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to return only events that are happening after `DateTime.now()` in Flutter. I am taking the events from cloud firestore and have declared the date and time under `event_date`.

This is my code:

```
new StreamBuilder(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Events')
        .orderBy('event_date', descending: false)
        .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData)
            return Text('Loading data... Please Wait');

            return new Container(
                height: 100.0,
                child: new ListView(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    children: snapshot.data.documents.map<Widget>((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                        if ((document.data()['event_date']).isAfter(now)) {
                            return new Card(
                                color: Color(0xff004FB2),
                                child: new Container(
                                    width: 100.0,
                                    height: 100.0,
                                    child: new Text(document.data()['title']),
                                ),
                            );
                        } else {
                            return Container();
                        }
                    }).toList(),
                ),
            );
        },
    ),
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Class 'Timestamp' has no instance method 'isAfter'.
Receiver: Instance of 'Timestamp'
Tried calling: isAfter(Instance of 'DateTime')
```

Any help would be appreciated as I have never used the `isBefore` or `isAfter` before so I am struggling a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try first converting your `Timestamp` object into a `DateTime` object

```
(document.data()['event_date']).toDate().isAfter(now)
```

or:

```
(document.data()['event_date']).toDate().isAfter(now.toDate())
```

let me know if it worked

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response! Unfortunately neither work. With the first, I get the error ```The argument type 'DateTime' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'.``` And with the second, I get the error ```The method 'toDate' isn't defined for the type 'DateTime'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'toDate'.```

Comment: ohh sory, i think i know the problem, ill edit

Comment: try one of those two ways now... its probably because Firebase Timestamp needs to be converted to DateTime in order for you to use isAfter on it

Comment: That is amazing, the first one works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution using Timestemp. It has the following public method:

```
public int compareTo (Timestamp other)
```

and also has

```
static Timestamp now()
```

so, you need to check

```
(document.data()['event_date']).compareTo(Timestamp.now())
```

Comment: It's fascinating that there's a compareTo, but not the traditional < = > operators.

Comment: comareTo returns int , so you need to check it against 0 with < = >